# Covariance with dictionary alternative?

Tags: c#

I'm outputting some classes fields to XML. I don't know what each field is, but I check if it's IEnumerable or IDictionary, because I need to handle fields one way, collections other, and dictionaries yet another way.

You can see my problem with the last method "DictionaryToXml". Dictionaries are not covariant. 
In other words 
`IDictionary<object, object> dict = new IDictionary<string, string>();` will throw exception

How to do that, any workaround?

```
        public static string ClassToXml(object o)
    {
        string observeable;
        observeable = o.GetType().ToString();
        XElement root = new XElement(observeable);

        FieldInfo[] fields = o.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (FieldInfo f in fields)
        {
            try
            {
                string nam = f.Name;
                if (f.FieldType.GetInterface("IDictionary") != null)
                {
                    XElement child = DictionaryToXml(o, f);
                    root.Add(child);
                }
                else if (f.FieldType.GetInterface("IEnumerable") != null && f.FieldType != typeof(string))
                {
                    XElement child = EnumerableToXml(o, f);
                    root.Add(child);
                }
                else
                {
                    XElement child = FieldToXml(o, f);
                    root.Add(child);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex) { continue; }
        }



        observeable = root.ToString();
        return "";
    }
    static XElement FieldToXml(object o, FieldInfo f)
    {
        string nam = f.Name;
        object val = f.GetValue(o);
        string stringed = val != null ? val.ToString() : "";
        XElement child = new XElement(nam, stringed, new XAttribute("type", "field"));
        return child;
    }
    static XElement EnumerableToXml(object o, FieldInfo f)
    {
        string nam = f.Name;
        XElement container = new XElement(nam, new XAttribute("type", "enumerable"));


        IEnumerable<object> vals = (IEnumerable<object>)f.GetValue(o);
        foreach (object obj in vals)
        {
            string stringed = obj.ToString();

            XElement child = new XElement("value", stringed);
            container.Add(child);
        }

        return container;
    }
    static XElement DictionaryToXml(object o, FieldInfo f)
    {
        string nam = f.Name;
        XElement container = new XElement(nam, new XAttribute("type", "dictionary"));

        IDictionary<object, object> dict = (IDictionary<object, object>)f.GetValue(o);
        List<KeyValuePair<object, object>> vals = dict.ToList();
        foreach (object obj in vals)
        {
            //some code
        }

        return container;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are checking for the non-generic [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, so why not use it?

```
static XElement DictionaryToXml(object o, FieldInfo f)
{
    string nam = f.Name;
    XElement container = new XElement(nam, new XAttribute("type", "dictionary"));

    IDictionary dict = (IDictionary)f.GetValue(o);
    foreach (DictionaryEntry obj in dict)
    {
        //some code using obj.Key and obj.Value
    }

    return container;
}
```

You *could* use more reflection to find out what type of dictionary you are using, but since you're only trying to cast to `<object, object>` there's no point - you get `object` keys and values from the non-generic interface.

(Similarly, you are *checking* for [`IEnuemrable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) but *casting* to [`IEnumerable<object>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx), which might trip you up.)